# reliable async batch kafka producer using spring cloud stream

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

i want to setup some transformation (consume from one topic, produce to another) using spring cloud stream. also i want it to be

- reliable - lets say 'at least once'
- fast produce - perform producer.flush() once per batch, not per message
- fast offset commit - perform commit once per batch from partition

with raw kafka client, or with spring-kafka i would do the next (assuming producer configured appropriately: acks=all,linger.ms > 0, batch-size is big enough and so on):

1. get consumed messages (lets say from consumer.poll())
2. do my custom tranformation for every message
3. producer.send(message).addCallback(...) for every message
4. producer.flush()
5. check that there were no errors in send callbacks
6. consumer.commit() - for highest offset

the question is how to achieve similar with spring-cloud-stream? i'm aware of consumer.batch-mode=true and producer.sync=false, but i'm not sure what is a right way to bind together reliable produce with offset commit

**UPDATE**
kinda a simple solution i came up with (note that beside of initial requirement i need dynamic routing with dynamic topic creation):

configuration

```
public class DynamicRouterCfg {

    @Autowired
    private BinderAwareChannelResolver outputResolver;

    @Autowired
    private DynamicRouterProducerListener dynamicRouterProducerListener;

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<List<byte[]>>> dynamicRouter() {
        return msgs -> {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                dynamicRouterProducerListener.setBatchSize(msgs.getPayload().size());

                for (byte[] payload : msgs.getPayload()) {
                    doBusinessLogic(payload);
                    outputResolver.resolveDestination(resolveDestination(payload))
                            .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload)
                            .build());
                }

                if (dynamicRouterProducerListener.waitForBatchSuccess()) {
                    Acknowledgment ack = (Acknowledgment) msgs.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT);
                    Objects.requireNonNull(ack).acknowledge();
                }

            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        };
    }

    private void doBusinessLogic(byte[] payload) {
        // placeholder for business transformation
    }

    private String resolveDestination(byte[] payload) {
        // some business logic for destination resolving
        return null;
    }

    private static class DynamicRouterProducerListener implements ProducerListener<Object, Object> {

        private volatile CountDownLatch batchLatch;

        public void setBatchSize(int batchSize) {
            this.batchLatch = new CountDownLatch(batchSize);
        }

        public boolean waitForBatchSuccess() {
            try {
                return batchLatch.await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ProducerRecord<Object, Object> producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata) {
            batchLatch.countDown();
        }

    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: dynamicRouter
    stream:
      bindings:
        dynamicRouter-in-0:
          destination: consumed.topic
          group: test.group
          consumer:
            batch-mode: true
            concurrency: 1
            header-mode: none
            use-native-decoding: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: broker:9092
          auto-create-topics: true
          required-acks: all
        bindings:
          router-in-0:
            consumer:
              auto-rebalance-enabled: false
              auto-commit-offset: false
              auto-commit-on-error: false
              configuration.fetch.max.bytes: 5024000
              configuration.isolation.level: read_committed
        default:
          producer:
            sync: false
            batch-timeout: 10 # as i see this one would be converted to linger.ms
            compression: gzip
            configuration:
              max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 1
              max.request.size: 5024000
            # i need to create topics with custom configuration
            topic.replication-factor: 2
            topic.properties:
              cleanup.policy: compact
              min.cleanable.dirty.ratio: 0.1
```

what drawbacks i can see here:

1. using deprecated BinderAwareChannelResolver: don't know how can i use `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` in my case
2. after every batch it would wait redundant ${batch-timeout}
3. not sure about guarantees of `producer.onSuccess` method (if "duplicated" success calls are possible), especially when messages from single incoming batch are routed to different topics

Comment: It's really not necessary to call `producer.flush()` since the batch will be sent after the linger time expires anyway. If you really want to flush there is probably a hack I could come up with. However, it will be difficult to know which record is the last one in the batch (unless you use batch mode).

Comment: I am working on a solution for the next release to optionally flush after a specific send.

Comment: thank you for your answer! guess incoming improvement would help. 
btw, `producer.flush` is not a requirement by itself, what i really need is to be sure that all produced messages were "acked" by the broker before committing offset

Comment: updated question with samples of possible solution that came to mind

Comment: Simply set the `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` message header in the output message. You don't need to worry about duplication successes (but if you want you can detect them by keeping track of the record metadata.